# Compile sources and objects list with clang using makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
src = $(wildcard src/*.c)
src_files = $(notdir ($src))
obj = $(src_files:%.c=build/%.o)
all: $(obj)

$(obj): $(src)
    clang ${clang_options} -c $(src) -o $@
```

If my makefile is written in this way, I can just iterate list `$(obj)` through `$@`.
How could I iterate both `$(obj)` and `$(src)` in one rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote means that any object file depends on **all** source files and is the result of the compilation of **all** source files. This is probably not what you want. Use a static pattern rule:

```
src = $(wildcard src/*.c)
src_files = $(notdir ($src))
obj = $(src_files:%.c=build/%.o)
all: $(obj)

$(obj): build/%.o: src/%.c
    clang ${clang_options} -c $< -o $@
```

This means that any object file depends on only **one** source file, with same base name, and is the result of its compilation.